# Hyperledger Composer network, how I run on multiple machines?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

i am studying in a research project using Hyperledger Fabric and Composer, i already managed to create the BNA file with the project running on Composer-playground and composer-rest-server. So, i want to run this project in a distributed ledger, to create the project i follow the Hyperledger composer tutorial, however this tutorial does not show how to create a distributed ledger through multiple peers, nor the Hyperledger fabric tutorial.

I follow this tutorial also https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/hyperledger-fabric-on-multiple-hosts-a33b08ef24f

but it did not work with the BNA file.

If anyone knows how to do it, please share.

Thank You.

Comment: Abdul Wahab's tutorial is written for Hyperledger Fabric only. Composer (being a development framework and tooling for developing blockchain apps and smart contracts) provides a single machine tutorial for multiple orgs (and therefore multi peers) https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org on its docs site - you would need to ensure your Fabric nodes/containers are resolvable and that the sample chaincode (in that tutorial) works fine across machines you configure.

Comment: Then configure your Composer connection profiles (as described in the tutorial) and build  business network cards to interact with the BNA you are installing onto the peers - you can do a single org, multi-machines, as indicated